# Connect to Oracle DB from Spring-jdbc with Oracle Wallet authentification

Tags: java, spring, oracle, authentication, jdbc

I was using Spring-jdbc with org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource using the username and password for the connection. I want to use BasicDataSource because I only have one connection.

I had this code:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" /> 
</bean>
```

Now I have to use authentication based in Oracle Wallet, I don't have problem in a simple application test without Spring but I can't integrate this new authentication with Spring. Does anyone know How I can do it??

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you wish to store the user's password in the wallet? Or do you wish to store a certificate in the wallet to then use SSL connections? If what you want to do is use SSL then do you also want to authentication the database user through the client's certificate?

Answer (score 4):

You mention "simple application test" so I'm assuming you need to configure your unit tests. In a unit test config class (for example `class TestSpringWebConfig extends SpringWebConfig`) this gets you an Oracle datasource using a wallet (bonus: the following uses a proxy database account):

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "path/to/your/tnsnames");

OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("oracle.net.wallet_location", "(source=(method=file)(method_data=(directory=path/to/your/wallet)))");

/*
  Use the following only if you have a proxy user database account instead of a normal DB account
  A test user's username could go here though
*/
props.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_PROXY_CLIENT_NAME, "proxy-user-name"); 

ds.setConnectionProperties( props );
ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:/@dbAlias"); //dbAlias should match what's in your tnsnames

return ds;
```

This also assumes you have the following in your JDK:

In JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security, add the following to the "List of providers":

```
security.provider.11=oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider
```

And add the following jars from Oracle to JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext:

- osdt_cert.jar
- osdt_core.jar
- oraclepki.jar

And of course, all of the above assumes the ojdbc7 jar is in your application's classpath already.